# How to block certain IP adresses from accessing your website on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I was looking at my analytics today and I saw some accesses from a few countries in which I thought strange since my website is a "Shop" website and it is directed only for people in my country. I am currently hosting my website in Firebase and I have tried everything from looking at their documentation and tons of tech related blogs. All of them always talk about the .htaccess file that firebase does not have. I was wondering how to block an IP range with the firebase.json file.

Comment: Why do this? They may be in another country buying a present for some one in your country

Comment: Because we do not have an online store it is a physical store.

Comment: People may be travelling to your country.  Also vpn

Comment: Such unexpected/surprising visits are usually a kind of attack flooding your data with referrals on malicious sites. It's hard to block it as those attackers, usually originating in Russia, use Tor, and tech like this. GA, Firebase, Google generally does not care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature of Firebase Hosting.  You can submit a feature request by contacting [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).